# Error adding libxml2 to project

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4, google-api, libxml2

I am getting this error:

> /Users/AppleMacbook/Documents/Tab/Tab/../../../Downloads/GDataXMLNode.h:38:24: error: libxml/tree.h: No such file or directory

I have added these two properly:

```
/usr/include/libxml2

other linkers flags   -lxml2
```

Still I am getting an error saying that tree.h is not present. I opened that folder, it's there!

Could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need /usr/include/ instead or in addition?  I notice it's looking for libxml/tree.h but you're including /usr/include/libxml2 ?

Comment: This is the path. `usr/include/libxml2/libxml/tree.h`

Comment: I don't have Xcode in front of me but in the project setup there are 2 places to list library includes and user-defined includes IIRC.  Try to put /usr/include/libxml2/ in both of those places and maybe also check the "recursive" option.

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428847/libxml-tree-h-no-such-file-or-directory exact duplicate?

Comment: Nope I already checked that question. Adding those two cleared his problem. Did you try in ios sdk 5.0 ?

Comment: Could potentially be a bug in the beta Xcode 4.2.x... I know I use 4.2.(1?) and include `/usr/include/mysql/` with no issues using this exact type of project setup. I also know I've hit bugs with the beta clang.  If you can't solve, install Xcode 4.0.2.  If it's a regression, report it to Apple.

Comment: The bug I found had me spend 3 days with cryptic errors trying to cross-compile a gcc.  Talk about FML, wow.  GL

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify an include path, in addition to a linker path `-I/usr/include/libxml2/libxml`, just specify the path (`/usr/include/libxml2/libxml`) in the build settings.
[image]

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean by `you need to specify an include path, in addition to a linker path -I/usr/include/libxml2/libxml, ` ?

Comment: added image to explain better.

Comment: Yeah. I had already done this. I still got the error dude. And that is what I have posted in the question.

Comment: if you open the terminal and type "cat /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/tree.h" does it read out?

Comment: try just throwing this in as a gcc flag -I/usr/include/libxml2/