# Objective C Error on #include <libxml/tree.h>

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am trying to setup a touchxml library and getting an error libxml/tree.h no such file or directory. I added the linker flags and the header search paths as follow:
/usr/include/libxml2
and linker flag
-lxml2

I have looked all the documentation, but no go. Can someone help me on this?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [libxml/tree.h no such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428847/libxml-tree-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 6):

Ok I got it to work
I was putting the /usr/include/libxml2 into User header search paths instead of header search path.