# hpple : 'libxml/tree.h' file not found

Tags: ios, hpple

When I use hpple and build, aways show " 'libxml/tree.h' file not found " error.

I have ，
set [Header Search Path] "${SDKROOT}/usr/include/libxml2" 
set [Other Linker Flag] value as "-lxml2"

Comment: possible duplicate of [libxml/tree.h no such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428847/libxml-tree-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oh, sorry, I just set the TARGETS's Build Settings forgot set the PROJECT -->Build Settings.

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1:** Target--> In Build settings-->Header search path-->press return(enter) key--->replace `/usr/include/libxml2`

**Step 2:** Target--> In Build phase--> confirm it whether  `"libxml2.dylib"` framework is present, if not added

**Step 3:** Target--> In Build phase--> search `libxml2.dylib` then click add button

**Refer Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Note: for step 1, in later XCode versions (6.x, 7.x, etc.) use this for the header search path: $(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2 I think a problem in newer XCode is a lack of the parentheses around SDKROOT.