# Error linking libxml

Tags: objective-c, ios, gdata, libxml2

I want to use GData API in my project for iOS
I've followed official notes on how to add GData to project
Static library was built successfully, I've added references to it and headers folder
Than I put `#import "GData.h` into one of my source files and get following error while building project:`libxml/tree.h : no such file or directory`

In build settings - other linker flags I've specified -lxml2 (both for project and target)
In header search paths - /usr/include/libxml2 (no misspellings, I've checked), both for project and target. "${SDKROOT}/usr/include/libxml2" also didn't help

Still get the same errors

Mac OS 10.6.6, Xcode 4.0 Build 4A304a, iOS SDK 4.3

Comment: The following question may shed some light on this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428847/libxml-tree-h-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: I've added libxml2.dylib to build phases - link binary with libraries, but that doesn't help too.

Comment: any luck getting it right?? Im stuck with the same problem :(

Answer (score 1):

Try this:  Project target-->Build Setting-->Header Search Path, Debug mode, ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/Headers