# wsdl2objc: 'libxml/tree.h' file not found

Tags: objective-c, ios, wsdl2objc

After i checked all [this](http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/wiki/UsageInstructions) instructions (original wsdl2objc documentation), i get this error:

> 'libxml/tree.h' file not found

I checked several forum entries, because i'm not alone with this problem. Sadly nothing that worked for the others worked for me. I use XCode 4.2.

Please help! Thy

Comment: Check this path(/usr/include/libxml2) have libxml2 folder is there or not.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This entry [libxml/tree.h no such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428847/libxml-tree-h-no-such-file-or-directory) and the video http://sudzc.com/Tutorial/ObjC.mov helped me.

The solution was that i didn't have to add the libxml2.dylib in the "Linked Framework and Libraries" section, so i just deleted it, because i added it previousely.

Then in the Project -> "Build Settings" Tap i added the value "-lxml2" in the "Other Linker Flags" entry and in the "Header Search Paths" i added the value "/usr/include/libxml2".

Thats it.

Comment: i am having the same problem but in "Header Search paths" i added the "$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2" then this problem is fixed

Comment: thanks a lot...       I used Header Search Paths" value "/usr/include/libxml2".

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked after I had added not "/usr/include/libxml2", 
but "**${SDKROOT}/usr/include/libxml2**" in Header Search Paths. 
Also I added "-lxml2" in "Other Linker Flags".

I had no need to set up Project's settings, just Target's. XCode 6.1