# How to solve iPhone app hpple HTML Parsing 'libxml/tree.h' file not found?

Tags: iphone, ios, compiler-errors, html-parsing, hpple

I am trying to parse HTML URL content using hpple for iPhone app. I want to parse and get data from like this URL http://www.example.com/mobile/403.html. I have used Google and found `hpple for HTML parsing`. I got the sample HTML parsing hpple code from `github`. When i start to run the project the below error is occurring

`'libxml/tree.h' file not found`

I have added this line `${SDKROOT}/usr/include/libxml2 in project->build->header search paths` but not it is looking like this `iPhoneos3.1.2/usr/include/libxml2/**` and also i have included `libxml2.dylib and libxml2.2.dylib` in my project. Am working in XCode 4.2. Could you please help to solve this error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577912/libxml2-tree-h-not-found-in-my-xcode-project/10577987#10577987

Comment: @elppa Thank you. I have added libxml2 framework already. And added ${SDKROOT}/usr/include/libxml2 in Project->Build->Header Search Path. Still am getting the same error. Can you please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: r u use beta xcode version ya xcode

Comment: Thank you. No am not using beta version of Xcode. Currently am using XCode 4.2 version for development. I need your help Mr.Elppa. Thanks.

Comment: follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428847/libxml-tree-h-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: @elppa Thank you. just i have tried the steps in your provided link but still am getting the same error. Any idea. Thanks.

Comment: can you check, libxml2.dylib has checked marked in target membership. If not then checked it and compile.

Comment: @Atif Thanks for your comment. Could you please tell me clearly? I can't understand? Thanks in advance.

Comment: First select dylib file in project navigator (left side) then show utilities (right side) select file inspector. There is the tab name Target Membership. Make sure the dylib file must be selected. Because I have face this problem one time and don't know how it will unselected.

Comment: @Atif Yes it is selected (Checked). But still the error is occurring. What to do? Can you please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure, but check your Base SDK in Project > Build Setting it will be 3.1.2 thats the reason it show

> iPhoneos3.1.2/usr/include/libxml2/**

Change to latest iOS then it will update your iPhoneosX.X/usr/include/libxml2/** then compile it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add this line:

```
${SDKROOT}/usr/include/libxml2
```

in TARGETS->build->header search paths...

and make sure that you copied your hpple files into your project like this...

[image]

[image]

Good luck and hope this helps!