# #import <libxml/tree.h> file not found after xcode 6.1 update

Tags: ios, build, xcode6, libxml2, gdataxml

I am getting lexical or preprocessor issue i.e  file not found after xcode 6.1 update. i have followed below stack overflow solution but no luck.

[#import <libxml/tree.h> file not found after xcode update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14622684/import-libxml-tree-h-file-not-found-after-xcode-update)

```
i found libxml2.2.dylib --> it is created during xcode 5 installation.
              libxml2.dylib  --> it is created during latest xcode6 update.
```

Using finder /usr/lib/

```
I had used libxml2.2.dylib in xcode 5 but now i am getting above error in xcode 6.
```

Also how to add libxml2.2.dylib lib from this /usr/lib/ location because in build Phase i can not navigate to /usr/lib/ path.

Please help me out. thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428847/libxml-tree-h-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577912/libxml2-tree-h-not-found-in-my-xcode-project  look at those links may help you

Comment: Saurbh Prajapati your solution didnt help me

Comment: i m also using xcode 6 and i hv same problem also but this posts help me a lot

Comment: how you resolved, i had followed same like that but still no luck

Answer (score 14, accepted):

in SearchPaths in both Project as well as in target

```
set HeaderSearchPath and LibrarySearchPaths to /usr/include/libxml2
```

this thing solve my issue may it will also help you

also set OTHER_LDFLAGS to -lxml2 to avoid any linker issues afterwards

Comment: also set OTHER_LDFLAGS to -lxml2 to avoid any linker issues afterwards