# iOS Library not found for -lidn (Including xmppframework)

Tags: xcode

I'm trying to include the xmppframework in my xcode project however I've come to a problem. I get the following error when trying to compile:

```
Path 'Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/usr/lib/lixml2.dylib following -F not a directory
Library not found for -lidn
```

I have followed the instructions to setup xmppframework from [here](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/wiki/GettingStarted_iOS) and followed [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10904246/909446) instructions to make sure all the paths are correct, however I'm still getting the error.

I've checked the file path and it's definitely there..

Is there any other reason for this error? Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally fixed it after 3 days..

My advice to anyone else coming across this problem is to load up one of the example projects and compare the build settings on each! Ended up that my Library Search Paths was wrong.