# Opening import file for module 'Swift': Not a directory

Tags: swift, libxml2

After following the instructions here to setup libxml on Swift:
[libxml/tree.h no such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428847/libxml-tree-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

I encountered an error while compiling which said:

```
Opening import file for module 'Swift': Not a directory
```

I've searched online and they recommending cleaning the project which didn't work for me. Any idea what's causing this error?

Answer (score 2):

I got this error when I had an invalid path to a framework in my `Framework Search Path` and `User Header Search Paths`.
I simply fixed the path by adding ".framework" to the end of the path, to make the path valid, and this error went away.

Answer (score 1):

Issue cropped up after adding my first swift class to the project.

I fixed it by going into the build settings for ALL targets (including the actual project) and remove any erroneous paths from `Framework Search Path`.

Specifically:

1. Simplified the main target to:

   `$(inherited)`

   `$(SRCROOT)`
2. And by removing an old, erroneous path to `libxml2` on the project.