# opening import file for module 'onesignal' not a directory

Tags: ios, swift, onesignal

i am using OneSigan for Push notification and i got the below error while building the app

[image]

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28271455/opening-import-file-for-module-swift-not-a-directory) answer.

Answer (score 0):

fixed , i used old version from Onsignal from Pod components